# SQL WHERE statement won't respect a string generated by Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL table that has the following `CREATE TABLE` statement which was made by Laravel PHP framework:

```
CREATE TABLE `mediables` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `mediable_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `mediable_type` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `media_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_mediables_media_id` (`media_id`),
  KEY `mediables_mediable_type_mediable_id_index` (`mediable_type`,`mediable_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_mediables_media_id` FOREIGN KEY (`media_id`) REFERENCES `medias` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3837 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Running the statement `SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type LIKE '%\Family%';` gives me one result as follows:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| id   | created_at          | updated_at          | deleted_at | mediable_id | mediable_type     | media_id |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
| 3836 | 2020-02-06 17:39:19 | 2020-02-06 17:39:19 | NULL       |           4 | App\Models\Family |      126 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------+----------+
```

If I change my query to any of the following, I get 0 results back:

```
SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type = 'App\Models\Family';
SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type LIKE 'App\Models\Family';
SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type LIKE '%s\Family%';
SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type LIKE '%Models\Family%';
SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type LIKE '%App\Models\Family%';
```

What I need to do is return results where `mediable_id = 4 AND mediable_type = 'App\Models\Family'`.  Why does this condition fail to return results?

Comment: Your not tempted to normalise the schema?

Comment: Its not happy with the slashes. Why don't you setup a separated table for mediable with id and mediable_type

Comment: @Strawberry The tables are made by https://twill.io so I'm not comfortable breaking from their conventions as it might break other out-of-the-box-functionality.

Comment: A backslash is an escape caracter in MySQL strings which needs to be escaped with another backslash: `mediable_type = 'App\\Models\\Family'`. This is different when you bind the value as parameter of a prepared statement. If you write the query string in PHP with a hardcoded value, you might even need to use "quadrobackslashes", since it's also an escape caracter in PHP strings.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Worked in mysql terminal.  But this in PHP still gives zero results `DB::select("SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_type LIKE '%Models\\\\Family%'");`  I've tried using anywhere from 1 to 8 backslashes, between the words Models and Family but still no results.  Any suggestions?

Comment: 4 slashes [should work](https://rextester.com/RSJT37993).

Comment: I got it work like this: `DB::select("SELECT * FROM mediables WHERE mediable_type LIKE '%Models".addslashes('\\\\')."Family%'");`